# jQuery add/remove class using 'this'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to append a class to a div when its click and remove when its clicked a second time I currently have this has my script -

```
    $(".project").click(function(){
        if ($(".project-expand", this).is(':visible')) {
            $(".project-expand",this).hide(1000);
            $('.project').delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(".project").removeClass('item-dropped').clearQueue();
          });
        } else if ($(".project-expand", this).is(':hidden')) {
            $(".project-expand").hide(1000);
            $(".project-expand",this).show(1000);
            $(".project").addClass('item-dropped');
        }
    });
```

But this adds the "item-dropped" class to all of my divs that have a class "project" when I change the code to -

```
$(".project", this).addClass('item-dropped');
```

It doesn't do anything, where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Do you mean `$(".project", $(this)).addClass('item-dropped');` ?

Comment: Can you post the HTML that this is being applied to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the class selector `$('.project')` you could simply use the target of the click event (`$(this)`):

```
$(".project").click(function () {
    var project = $(this);
    var projectExpand = $(".project-expand", this);

    if (projectExpand.is(':visible')) {
        projectExpand.hide(1000);
        project.delay(1000).queue(function () {
            project.removeClass('item-dropped').clearQueue();
        });
    } else if (projectExpand.is(':hidden')) {
        $(".project-expand").hide(1000);
        projectExpand.show(1000);
        project.addClass('item-dropped');
    }
});
```

Additional Info : 
The reason what you were trying to do didn't work originally is because `$('.project', this)` looks for elements with class `project` inside the current element (i.e. looking for a project inside a project)

Comment: @Zeetkings11 Added a little bit more info, explaining why what you were trying didn't work :)

Comment: @MartinErnst Good point, I've modified the code slightly to only create the necessary jQuery objects once

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $(this) to add class on the clicked item:

```
        $(".project").click(function(){
            if ($(".project-expand", this).is(':visible')) {
                $(".project-expand",this).hide(1000);
                $(this).delay(1000).queue(function(){
                $(this).removeClass('item-dropped').clearQueue(); // Here
              });
            } else if ($(".project-expand", this).is(':hidden')) {
                $(".project-expand").hide(1000);
                $(".project-expand",this).show(1000);
                $(this).addClass('item-dropped'); // Here
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use :

```
$(this).addClass('item-dropped');
```

[concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kko723o/)